# Returning response directly from HttpServer

Tags: c#, http, system.web

I can across this the other day and it has me perplexed and I was hoping to get some light shed on the subject as to why this behavior is occurring.

Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
public class MyHttpServer : HttpServer
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (someCondition)
        {
            return new Task<HttpResponseMessage>(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

I expected if some precondition was met, that I would get a bad response message back, but instead, it just spins forever until I stop the server and then the client gets a message along the lines, "No data received from the server."  What is causing this, and is it possible to return a response message from the server's `SendAsync` method?

Comment: Just as a guess, you want to return `Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest))` instead

Comment: @johnny5 You are correct sir, that seems to have fixed it.  Is that because it expects a running/completed task and not just a task?

Comment: I'm not sure what creating a new task that way does, I just know that when I already have the result to use From Result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return from result since you already have the response

```
return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest))
```